# Tastypie save Foreign Key ? (django, backbone.js)

Tags: backbone.js, tastypie

I have two Models in django

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
class Title(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    titlename = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And now I have the following tastypie

```
class TitleResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Title.objects.all()
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        filtering = {'id':ALL}
```

I want to store a new entry into my title table. So, I use the following save method of Backbone model

```
title.save({titlename: "ABC", book_id: 1})
```

The url is `/api/v1/title/`

But it will raise an error: book_id cannot be null. (I have an entry in *book* table which id is 1).

What method do i need to use? hydrate? or obj_create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I need write a *BookResource* and send back `{titlename: "123",book:/api/v1/book/1/}`